# Is F# in general and the F# plugin for MonoDevelop maintained for Linux?

Tags: f#, mono, monodevelop

I would like to play around with F# on my Linux box, but I struggle to find up-to-date versions of the relevant files. The F# [cross-platform packages](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/) are from 2010 and [the plug-in](http://functional-variations.net/monodevelop/) seems to be for Monodevelop 2.4 (I have 2.8 installed, which is not the newest anyway...). Is the project still alive? Am I looking at the right place?

Comment: http://fsharp.org/use/linux/ should have the latest information for using F# on linux.

Comment: @JamesMoore, it does indeed. And they released a ready made package for Debian Unstable a few days ago for the compiler, so installation is easier than ever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# cross-platform package is pretty outdated. Depending on which Linux distro you're using, F#  may be distributed with Mono 2.10.x (check [Mono homepage](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) for details). Otherwise, you should build [F# compiler from source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) for latest version.

[The original F# binding](http://functional-variations.net/monodevelop/) does not work with MonoDevelop 2.8. Fortunately, the F# binding is being actively developed by [Scott Stephens](https://github.com/scottstephens/fsharpbinding) under a Google Summer of Code project. There are first positive sights as being mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/group/fsharp-opensource/browse_thread/thread/f75bac5cd2f2f9c8#). For discussion, you can post on [F# Open Source Community Group](https://groups.google.com/group/fsharp-opensource) or ask questions here.

Comment: How do I install stuff from github? Do I have to compile it, or is there a pre-compiled version?

Comment: @Grzenio -  You will probably have to compile it

Comment: @Grzenio: you should compile them yourself. Get a git client, clone these repos and start playing with them :).

Answer (score 1):

The F# addin for Monodevelop is still developed as of 2014 and is available from addins.monodevelop.com.